# trainable parameters of vgg16 model get changed after adding my own dense layer

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, model, conv-neural-network, vgg-net

vgg16_model = tf.keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16()

model= Sequential()

for layer in vgg16_model.layers[:-1]:

```
model.add(layer)
```

model.summary()                   #The last dense layer is removed till now

[image]

for layer in model.layers:

```
layer.trainable=False         #for transfer learning i have freeze the layers
```

model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

model.summary()                    #now when i add dense layers trainable parameters of model get changed

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the first step you generate a network with 134,260,554 parameters.

Those parameter are all set to be non trainable.
Then you add a layer with two neurons to the model.
This adds 2*4096 + 2 = 8194 (weights + bias) parameters to the model.
Those parameters are trainable.
This is what the summary shows.

Comment: but if I remove this line "  layer.trainable=False " then I get all the parameters as trainable, but I think in transfer learning we have to set this to false??? I want to get all total parameters as a trainable parameters